# unexpected negative accuracy in SVD attempt

Tags: python, recommendation-engine, svd

I am having my first try with SVD, and I have encountered what looks like a silly issue, which I can't figure out.
Full disclosure: if this is an already asked question, can anybody point me to the right post, please? I couldn't find any; however, I might haven't searched for the proper tags.

The problem is that I get an Accuracy value that ranges from negative numbers to infinity, whereas I was expecting to range 0-100.
I copied the logic from coursework I did, and there the Accuracy was 0-100, but when I applied that logic here, the values changed.

Here's the code:

```
##STEP 1
#Creating the mock dataset
station = []
gender = []
hosp = []
business = []
school = []

for i in range(100):
    #station
    station.append(str(i+1)) 
    #gender
    gender.append(np.random.choice(np.arange(0,1,0.1)))

    #hosp
    hosp.append(np.random.choice(np.arange(0,5)))

    #business
    business.append(np.random.choice(np.arange(0,15)))

    #school
    school.append(np.random.choice(np.arange(0,10)))
    
mock = pd.DataFrame({'Station':station,
                     'Gender': gender,
                     'Hospitals': hosp,
                     'Business': business,
                     'Schools': school})

mock = mock.set_index('Station')

##STEP 2
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
mock_scl = scaler.fit_transform(mock)

##STEP 3
u, s, vt = np.linalg.svd(mock_scl)

##STEP 4
num_latent_feats = np.arange(1,mock_scl.shape[1],1)
sum_errs = []

for k in num_latent_feats:
    print('\n',k)
    # restructure with k latent features
    s_new, u_new, vt_new = np.diag(s[:k]), u[:, :k], vt[:k, :]
    
    # take dot product
    mock_est = np.around(np.dot(np.dot(u_new, s_new), vt_new))
    mock_est_scl = scaler.fit_transform(mock_est)
    # compute error for each prediction to actual value
    diffs = np.subtract(mock_scl, mock_est_scl)
    # total errors and keep track of them
    err = np.sum(np.sum(np.abs(diffs)))
    sum_errs.append(err)

##STEP 5
plt.plot(num_latent_feats, 1 - np.array(sum_errs)/mock_scl.shape[0]);
plt.xlabel('Number of Latent Features');
plt.ylabel('Accuracy');
plt.title('Accuracy vs. Number of Latent Features');
```

This is what I get

[image]

I thought was the scaler, but I still got the same chart with and without the scaler, unsurprisingly.

Thanks for any insight you guys can provide.

Comment: You normalise the sum of errors by dividing by `mock_scl.shape[0]`. Should this be `mock_scl.size` (because you calculate an error for every element of mock_scl, not just for every row or column)?

Comment: Thanks @slothrop, ```mock_scl.size``` fixed the accuracy range, however I think my all set up is incorrect. The ultimate goal is to create an engine which will provide me with the stations most similar to the provided one given the features (i.e. ```mock.columns```).